# definition in the header of a typedef

Tags: c++, coding-style, typedef

I want to ask about typedef definition.
I'm using pcl library and in tutorials sometimes I see the definition like this:

file.h

```
typedef pcl::PointXYZ PointT;
class File {...}
```

file.cpp

```
 pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer<PointT> ...
```

and other times they don't define the typedef into .h and they only put:

file.cpp

```
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>
```

Which one is better? one is more performante? is bad style?
Thanks!

Comment: Unless you edit your post and specify a programming language tag, nobody will read and reply to the post. Adding C++ tag.

Comment: If the `typedef` is meant to be part of the library's interface it needs to appear in the header, so clients can include the header and be able to refer to that type using the same name. OTOH, if a `typedef` is meant for internal use within the library, say, to save the author some keystrokes, it should appear within the cpp files to prevent namespace pollution.

Comment: What about shiny new using-style comments? They are shiny and they are new: `using pcl::PointXYZ = PointT;` and as we all know new is best.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference in performance. So, the only reason to use one above the other is the style.

Some coding rules (e.g., Linux kernel) suggest to not use typedefs, because they hide what you're really calling. However, if you know what you're doing, typedefs can save a lot of typing.

Comment: I agree. The same people that say don't use typedefs say don't use macros but both are useful when applied appropriately.